# How to return focus to dired window after killing buffer opened from dired?

Tags: dired, window, kill-buffer

Sometimes I use dired to view or edit several files in one folder, one after the other. Dired is open in one window, and I open the files in another window by typing `o` in dired. When I finish with one file and kill the associated buffer, I would like focus to switch back to the dired window, instead of remaining in the window that used to hold the buffer I just killed.

Comment: Does opening file in another windows is critical to your workflow? Using `<RET>` instead of `o` will open file in same window and after killing the file buffer dired buffer will remain in current window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-x 4 0` is bound to `kill-buffer-and-its-window`. It should do just what you're asking for in this context: kill the file buffer you're visiting and delete its window, putting you back in the previously selected window, which is the Dired window.

(Otherwise, as @muffinmad said in a comment, if you don't need to view the visited file in a separate window, but can instead view it in the window that Dired was using, then just use `f` or `RET` followed by `C-x k`.)

Comment: It must be `C-x k` instead of `C-x 0` because `C-x 0` will delete window but we want to kill buffer and stay in current window.

Comment: @muffinmad: Yes, thanks; corrected the typo.

Comment: This is what I need, thanks! I was originally thinking of something that would keep the second window open with another buffer in it, but actually there's no reason I need that.